# Typo3 Translation doesn't show default languge images

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

In typo3 I have english and german .English is default but duuring translation in german it doesn't show images

Comment: Please edit your question and state which version of TYPO3 you are using and which installation method you used (traditional or via composer). Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: typo3 version 8.7.24 installation via composer

Comment: I need to create blog extension in typo3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. You might want to add more information. But I will try to answer anyway.

After searching for "Pluswerk\Simpleblog\Controller\BlogController" I found https://github.com/plobacher/extbasebookexample. If that's what you're using, there is no composer.json there. When using composer with TYPO3, autoload is handled by composer, so if you add an extension without composer, it will not automatically autoload the classes. You can add the classes to your root composer.json:

```
{
  ...
  [Your other composer json]
  ...
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Pluswerk\\Simpleblog\\": "web/typo3conf/ext/pluswerk_simpleblog/Classes"
    }
  }
```

I don't know what your web directory is or what the directory of the extension is so you might have to change `web/typo3conf/ext/pluswerk_simpleblog/Classes`.

If you then execute `composer dumpautoload` it should add the classes to autoload.

If I did not interpret your problem correctly and you did install this extension using composer, can you add your root composer.json and the composer.json in the extension directory?